# Database read only error upgrading mediawiki database to 1.37

Tags: mediawiki

I have a 1.31 working mediawiki, and I'm trying to upgrade to 1.37. During update of the db the process stops this way:

```
Abort with control-c in the next five seconds (skip this countdown with --quick) ...3                                                                                                        0
...collations up-to-date.
...index rc_name_type_patrolled_timestamp already set on recentchanges table.
...rev_page_id index not found on revision.
...pl_namespace, tl_namespace, il_to indices are already non-UNIQUE.
...have ct_id field in change_tag table.
...rc_ip in table recentchanges already modified by patch patch-rc_ip_modify.sql.
...have el_index_60 field in externallinks table.
...ug_user_group key doesn't exist.
...have ug_expiry field in user_groups table.
...img_media_type in table image already modified by patch patch-add-3d.sql.
...ip_changes table already exists.
...index PRIMARY already set on categorylinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on templatelinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on pagelinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on text table.
...index PRIMARY already set on imagelinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on iwlinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on langlinks table.
...index PRIMARY already set on log_search table.
...index PRIMARY already set on module_deps table.
...index PRIMARY already set on objectcache table.
...index PRIMARY already set on querycache_info table.
...index PRIMARY already set on site_stats table.
...index PRIMARY already set on user_former_groups table.
...index PRIMARY already set on user_properties table.
...comment table already exists.
...revision_comment_temp table already exists.
...have ar_comment_id field in archive table.
Adding fa_description_id field to table filearchive ...Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBReadOnlyError from line 1088 of /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: Database is read-only: We are upgrading MediaWiki, please be patient. This wiki will be back in a few hours.
#0 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1372): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->assertIsWritablePrimary()
#1 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1323): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->executeQuery()
#2 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(5407): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query()
#3 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(5340): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->sourceStream()
#4 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(68): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->sourceFile()
#5 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/libs/rdbms/database/MaintainableDBConnRef.php(35): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->__call()
#6 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(704): Wikimedia\Rdbms\MaintainableDBConnRef->sourceFile()
#7 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(777): DatabaseUpdater->applyPatch()
#8 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(533): DatabaseUpdater->addField()
#9 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(497): DatabaseUpdater->runUpdates()
#10 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/maintenance/update.php(193): DatabaseUpdater->doUpdates()
#11 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(108): UpdateMediaWiki->execute()
#12 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/maintenance/update.php(264): require_once('/var/wwwc/catho...')
#13 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-all/update_subdomain.php(30): include('/var/wwwc/catho...')
#14 {main}
```

I know I had locked the database before upgrading, does that prevents database upgrade?

Comment: Yes, it does. Yes, it does.

Comment: ? I can't understand

Comment: Yes, you should unlock the database before running `update.php`.